# Hololens 2 は Hololens 2 Development EditionじゃなくてもMR開発することは可能かどうか

Tags: ios, c#, unity3d

研究でMR開発をする予定で、Hololens 2の購入を検討しています。
そこで、公式のドキュメントを見ていてふと疑問に思ったことがあるので、ぜひ有識者に教えてもらいたいです。

Hololens 2 は Hololens 2 Development EditionじゃなくてもMR開発することは可能かどうかを聞きたいです。

Comment: 有識者では無いですがこの辺[HoloLens 2 オプションの比較](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/hololens/hololens2-options),[HoloLens 2 と HoloLens 2 Development Edition の違いは何ですか?](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/hololens/hololens2-development-edition-faq#hololens-2---hololens-2-development-edition----------),[HoloLens 2 の任意のエディションを使用して開発できますか?](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/hololens/hololens2-development-edition-faq#hololens-2------------------------)に書かれているのでは？ `内部エンタープライズ アプリケーション`や`チェックアウト プロセス中に識別された特定の権利`が必要無いのならば`HoloLens 2 のどのエディションでもアプリの開発に使用できます。`なのだと思われます。

Comment: その辺り見落としていました、ありがとうございます！上記に該当しないのでMR開発ができそうです。